# Desperately Need Solution For This Proof, Anyone?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing

Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are non-constant real-valued differentiable functions $\in\Bbb R$

Furthermore, suppose that
$f(x + y) = f(x)f(y) − g(x)g(y)$ and $g(x + y) = f(x)g(y) + g(x)f(y)\ \forall\ x,y.$

If $f′(0) = 0$, prove that $(f(x))^2 + (g(x))^2 = 1\ \forall\ x.$

Firstly apologies for the format. Unfortunately this proof was meant to be the focus of a group project, but now with the deadline looming the group has let me down and quite frankly I have no idea how to prove this. I only need the proof to present in the form of a poster. If anyone could provide a proof I would be extremely grateful.

Thanks,

Callum

Comment: All looks rather trigonometric to me.

Comment: Related: [Defining sine and cosine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078377/defining-sine-and-cosine).

Comment: Hint: Look at $f(x)+ig(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

With $h(x)=f(x)^2+g(x)^2$, some elementary algebra gives you $$h(x+y)=[f(x)f(y) − g(x)g(y)]^2+[f(x)g(y) + g(x)f(y)]^2=[f(x)^2+g(x)^2][f(y)^2+g(y)^2]=h(x)h(y).$$
Under your assumptions, that means $h(x)=c^x$. Your equations with $x=y=0$ give $g(0)=0$ and $f(0)=1$ (since the functions are not constant, otherwise $f=g=0$ would be a solution, too), so $h'(0)=2f'(0)f(0)+2g'(0)g(0)=0$. Thus, $c=1$, and $h(x)=1$ for all $x$.