# Defining sine and cosine from functional equations $(S(x))^2+(C(x))^2=1$, $C(x+y)=C(x)C(y)-S(x)S(y)$, etc

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, definition, functional-equations

Let $\text{S}(x)$ and $\text{C}(x)$ be non-constant, continuous, real functions such that the following properties are true.

> (i) $\,\,\,\,(\text{S}(x))^2+(\text{C}(x))^2=1$
>
> (ii)$\,\,\,\,\text{C}(x+y)=\text{C}(x)\text{C}(y)-\text{S}(x)\text{S}(y)$
>
> (iii)   $\,\,\text{S}(x+y)=\text{S}(x)\text{C}(y) +\text{C}(x)\text{S}(y)$
>
> (iv)   $\,\,\,\text{S}(0)=0$
>
> (v)$\,\,\,\,\,\text{C}(0)= 1$

Do these properties uniquely define $\text{S}$ and $\text{C}$? (specifically do they define $\sin$ and $\cos$--although that would follow if $\text{S}$ and $\text{C}$ are uniquely defined)

If these three properties are not enough, can we add periodic properties to make them unique?

i.e.

> $\text{(vi)}\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{S}(x+2\pi)=\text{S}(x)\,\,\,\,$
>
> $\text{(vii)}\,\,\,\,\text{C}(x+2\pi)=\text{C}(x)$

This is similar to [Defining sine and cosine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1078377/545726) but without using limit properties and adding (i) and potentially (iv) and (v).

What properties can we add that are not from analysis to make them unique?

Comment: $S(x)=0$ and $C(x)=1$ satisfy all of these properties, so you'd have to exclude this case.

Comment: oh i see good catch

Comment: Possibly relevant question (particularly the first 2 answers): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303044/axiomatic-definition-of-sin-and-cos?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: If you define $E(x) = C(x) + iS(x)$ then the addition formula (ii) and (iii) gives us $E(x+y) = E(x)E(y)$ and condition (i) gives $E(x)E^*(x) = 1$. If we now assume $E(x)$ is non-constant and continuous at a single point (think this is enough) then $E(x) = e^{kix}$ for some real constant $k$ so a periodic condition would then be enough. The condition $C(0) = 1$ and $S(0) = 0$ is not needed since it already follows from (ii) and (iii).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without continuity or nonconstantness assumption on $C$ and $S$, I would like to note that the conditions (ii) and (iii) already imply that either both $C$ and $S$ are identically zero, or (i), (iv), and (v) hold.  From now on, we suppose that $C$ and $S$ obey both (ii) and (iii), and that they are nonconstant.

We can show that, for some (nonconstant) function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)\text{ for any }x,y\in\mathbb{R}\,,\tag{*}$$ we have $$C(x)=\cos\big(f(x)\big)\text{ and }S(x)=\sin\big(f(x)\big)$$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Equation (*) is known as Cauchy's functional equation, and there are nontrivial functions $f$ (which are not continuous) that satisfy (*).

If, in addition, either $C$ or $S$ is continuous, then both are continuous and there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $$f(x)=\lambda\, x$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Hence, (ii) and (iii) along with continuity of $C$ and $S$, as well as nonconstantness of $C$ and $S$, show that there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $$C(x)=\cos(\lambda \,x)\text{ and }S(x)=\sin(\lambda\, x)$$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$.  (Notice that, when $\lambda =0$, we get another constant solution: $C(x)=1$ and $S(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.)

If you further assume (along with (ii), (iii), continuity, and nonconstantness) that either $C$ or $S$ is periodic with minimal period $P$, then both are periodic with minimal period $P\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, then $$C\left(\frac{P}{4}\right)=0\text{ and }S\left(\frac{P}{4}\right)=\pm 1\,.$$  If $s:=\sin\left(\dfrac{P}{4}\right)$, then $s\in\{-1,+1\}$ and $\lambda=s\dfrac{2\pi}{P}$, so $$C(x)=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{P}\,x\right)\text{ and }S(x)=s\,\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{P}\,x\right)$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Particularly when $P=2\pi$, you get $$C(x)=\cos(x)\text{ and }S(x)=s\,\sin(x)$$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Unless there are other required properties, this is the best you can do with the conditions you put in your questions.  For example, if you also require that $S(x)>0$ for every sufficiently small $x>0$, then you will get $s=+1$.

The user [The_Sympathizer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11172/the-sympathizer) suggests (in a deleted answer) adding the condition $$\lim_{x\to 0}\,\frac{S(x)}{x}=1.$$
In this case, all we need are (ii), (iii), and the equation above in order to get that $C(x)=\cos(x)$ and $S(x)=\sin(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.  (This is a great suggestion by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to consider translations. If you translate $S$ and $C$ by any number $t$, the resulting functions have the same properties. So you need initial conditions such as : $S(0) = 0$ and $C(0) = 1$.

Comment: updated the question to have those conditions